# wp_remote_get() request failed when requested from certain server

Tags: php, wordpress, api, wp-api

I'm creating a WordPress plugin for my client using WP REST API V2, 
and i got a problem with the `wp_remote_get()` function,

My `wp_remote_get()` always return "http_request_failed" when I send the get request to the server from the client-side plugin,

BUT its weirdly works well when I try the `wp_remote_get()` in other domain or when I send the request to other url,

I use this simple code

```
$allstores = wp_remote_get( 'http://admin.shopsaver.dk/wp-json/wp/v2/shop', array( 'timeout' => 20 ) );
var_dump( $allstores );
```

Please help :)
Thank you

Comment: Does the server that fails have cURL enabled?

Comment: yes, and it works when i request to other url